# Execute Sqlite query on Android studio

Tags: sql, android-studio-3.0

I have a query  that I need to run in Android studio, but I can't figure out how to run the SQL query, or where to run it within Android studio. I am new to SQL.

This is the query I need to run:

CREATE TABLE "events" 
(
 `_id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
`message` TEXT NOT NULL, `reminder` TEXT NOT NULL,
 `end` TEXT
 );

Answer (score 0):

You can install SQLScout plugin on Android studio which has the ability to create, view, manage sqlite database.